# How to show characters in JPassword

Tags: java, passwords, character

getPassword() gives me an array of chars, but I want the password which looks like this `******` to shows up like this `MyPaSwOrd`, how can I do that ?

Guys I don't wanna extract the password, I just wanna write like " Enter your Password " inside the JPasswordField(), and when the user clicks on it, this goes away, and then he types his own password, which is like this * * * * * *

Comment: I just wanna add stuff like " Enter your Password", when the user clicks on the field, this goes away, then he types his password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two ways:

1. use the setEchoChar method (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#setEchoChar%28char%29)) and set a value of 0 (like the JavaDoc explains)
2. use a common JTextField

EDIT:

If you want to have a text like "Enter PW" in your field that disappears on a click, then try something like this:

```
public class JPassword {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        final JPasswordField field = new JPasswordField();

        field.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {

                char c = 0;
                field.setEchoChar(c);
                field.setText("Enter PW");

            }

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {

                char c = 1;
                field.setEchoChar(c);
                            field.setText("");
            }
        });

        char c = 0;
        field.setText("Enter PW");
        field.setEchoChar(c);

        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JButton("test"));
        frame.getContentPane().add(field);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Note: You need to check whether the user has entered a password or not. If he had, don't execute the focuseGained method. Otherwise the password will disappear. But this shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String password = new String(passwordField.getText());
```

However, the documentation explicitly states that you shouldn't be using Strings for checking/manipulating/passing password information.

[This explains how to check char[] passwords.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html)

**EDIT :**

You can have an ordinary `JField` with "Enter here your password" as its `text` and put a click `listener` on it. whenever a user clicks on it, remove the `JTextField` and replace it with `JPassword` wih having the focus

Answer (score 0):

**Dirty Way**

make one passwordfield and a text field... When you check the box, passwordField will be made invisible and textbox visible.

while in the unchecked condition, passwordField will be visible and textfield invisible.

and finally, make the textfield to copy the text entered in passwordField.